# PHP Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

im new in PHP and I want to know about PHP Zend Framework. What tools softwares do i need to install first? I've been searching a lot from google. But I also need to ask from an experienced developer (PHP), or any tips, reference, etc that could be of any help for a beginner like me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The Zend Framework is definitely not a good choice for a newbie. Better start without a framework.

Comment: very broad question. try to scale it down. also listen to @Niko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will refer you to this tutorial that has been very useful to me a while ago: [Creating and Running a Zend Framework Example Project](http://files.zend.com/help/previous-version/Zend-Studio-6/creating_and_running_a_zend_framework_example_project.htm)

Best way to start for a beginner is probably to setup an example and start from it and decline it to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for this one. also i'd like to ask if is there any tools or softwares that I need to use for me to use PHP? any tips?

Comment: Personally, I code with Notepad++ and use Wamp as a local server, but this subject is highly documented if you do a Google search. Also, if you have experience in other languages and MVC programming, this is more easy with Zend.

Comment: I see, actually this will be my 1st day and 1st hour to practice PHP, but thank you for the tips. :)

Comment: This question is redundant. To see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633314/how-to-start-with-zend-framework

Answer (score 1):

There are no special software tools that are required to work with Zend Framework.  Whatever tools you'd use to write PHP code are what you'd need for ZF.  You can use any text editor, but I prefer an IDE such as [Eclipse PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/).

To start a Zend Framework project, it's probably good to use their [Quick Start tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html) and branch out from there.